# OpenVPN - Docker (¿Cómo ver los usuarios conectados?

Tags: docker

He realizado una instalación de OpenVPN a mi contenedor Docker, pero tengo la curiosidad de cómo ve los conectados.
Ya qué quisiera saber qué usuario le puedo asignar una conexión directa con la impresora, pero no encuentro dónde puedo visualizar la conexión de ellos.

Referencia de OpenVPN - Docker:
https://github.com/kylemanna/docker-openvpn

Comment: [aqui](https://serverfault.com/questions/571592/how-to-view-connected-users-to-open-vpn-server) hay varias respuestas, parece ser que hay que agregar una ruta de administracion en /etc/openvpn/server.conf, osea que este archivo quizá lo puedas pasar con -v en el run, además de habilitar el puerto que pongas como direccion de adminitración.